# How to get the fields of the entity?

Tags: entities, 8

I need to get all the names of the entity, my entity is called 'a_process'? 
How can I write such query in Drupal 8?

```
$nodes = entity_load_multiple('a_process', $name);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the entity type manager to load entities of any type:

```
$entities = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('a_process')
  ->loadMultiple();

foreach ($entities as $entity) {
  // ...
}
```

If your code is in a container aware context, be sure to inject the entity manager as a service instead of referring to `\Drupal` explicitly.

Of course if you always know the entity type up-front you can use the method on the entity class itself, eg

```
$entities = \Drupal\foo\Entity\AProcess::loadMultiple()
```

Comment: But I need to reach only 'name' field, with this code I get an endless array

Comment: Well no, not endless. You can get field values through magic methods, so `$entity->name->value`, for example, if your field is called `name`

Comment: Hey, Clive :) You are my last hope. Still struggling with the fields. Now I am having a 'file' field. And after declaration the field in my content entity, the field was split into three: file__target_id, file__description, file__display in my database. How can I reach the field file__target_id ? the standard method $entity->file__target_id->value doesn't work (((

Comment: Found the solution in 10 seconds after posting the comment: $entity->file->target_id works :)